# Will Europe soon have more Muslims than Christians?

Tags: politics, islam, europe, demographics

This story, which appeared in the UK tabloid The Sun (and widely repeated elsewhere), has also been doing the rounds on social media.

The [original story](http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/7106420/Europe-to-very-soon-have-more-Muslims-than-Christians-Belgian-minister-warns-against-making-an-enemy-of-Islam-at-Brussels-attacks-hearing.html,) has the strapline:

> Muslims will soon outnumber Christians in Europe, a Belgian government minister has claimed.

The remark was made by Koen Geens at a meeting investigating the terrorist attacks in Brussels.

The headline was repeated widely (e.g. [Breitbart](http://www.breitbart.com/london/2016/04/27/europe-muslims-christians-bad-idea-make-enemy-islam/)), and text of the article includes a more nuanced claim:

> Speaking at the EU Parliament, Mr Geens said: “In Europe, very shortly we’re soon going to have more practising Muslims than practising Christians.”

Is either version of the claim true? Will there soon be more Muslims than Christians in Europe (even if we just count the practising)?

Comment: Let's keep the comments on how to improve the question, thank you. Feel free to use the [chat] for other stuff

Answer (score 24):

### October 2017 update below. (Graph updated May 2019)

Original answer:

**Self-declared identity**

According to the Pew Research Center, which seems to be the main group analyzing the demographics here, [Europe is projected to retain its Christian majority, but religious minorities will grow](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2015/04/15/europe-projected-to-retain-its-christian-majority-but-religious-minorities-will-grow/).

Even accounting for the increase in immigration since this post was written in April 2015, Christianity should apparently be about 50-65% of the population in 2050. This also accounts for a presumed growth of atheism and generational population change. Of course, this is quite different from the almost monoreligious culture that Europeans have taken for granted up until recently, but the claim that Christians will soon be a "minority" doesn't strictly match demographic trends.

If we remove the word "practicing" from Mr. Geens' claim, it doesn't seem very likely under common sense assumptions about demographics.

**Practicing believers**

I will have to do a bit of original research here, since I was unable to find any media reports on this.

[In 2004, Gallup reported](http://www.gallup.com/poll/13117/religion-europe-trust-filling-pews.aspx) that church attendance was at 3-5% in Denmark, Sweden, and Finland, and similarly low in France and Germany. This was not based on their own poll, but on an EU initiative called the [European Social Survey](http://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/).

[image: 2004 graph]

**May 2019: Here's an updated graph from 2014-2016 showing church attendance of young people only, by country. Orange indicates weekly church attendance. From [St Mary's University](https://www.stmarys.ac.uk/research/centres/benedict-xvi/docs/2018-mar-europe-young-people-report-eng.pdf)**

[image]

Do these figures include Muslims? Basically, no. In fact it is very hard to measure Muslims by the survey criteria. Jaak Billiet and Bart Meuleman explain in their 2008 study "[Religious diversity in Europe and its relation to social attitudes and value orientations](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/handle/123456789/197198)":

> During the equivalence tests, we have found that the set of items that
>   we have developed for the ESS core is not really suitable for
>   non-Christian religions such as Islam. One of the reasons for this was
>   exposed: the indicator of participation in public religious service
>   does not function for Muslim women. In view of future research in Europe, an alternative indicator must be found.

In plain language, Muslim women don't go to mosque, so "attendance" is not a proper measure of their religiosity. Hence the EU had to start a separate survey called [EURISLAM](http://www.eurislam.eu/) (*dead link*) to employ some "alternative indicators". However, the authors of this survey were hesitant to report their results publicly, as they explain in [a paywalled article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/1369183X.2015.1103032):

> calculating relative religiosity seems to be risky when the
>   significance of frequency of prayer is inherently difficult to compare
>   between Muslims for which the prayer is only one of the five
>   fundamental religious obligations and, for instance, Christians.

Since that article gave precisely no information whatsoever about what results they found for the religiosity question, I looked to the [full presentation of results](http://www.eurislam.eu/var/WP4_Integrated_report_on_survey_analysis.pdf), only to find:

> We refrain from presenting these here to keep the number of tables and
>   pages limited. We will extensively report on these results in further
>   publications.

Their page for the [religiosity survey](http://www.eurislam.eu/page=site.workpackage/id=3) (*dead link*) also has an empty section under "Results".

All I can say about this survey is that some parts of the [final report](http://www.eurislam.eu/var/EURISLAM_Final_Integrated_Research_Report_1.pdf) (*dead link*, large PDF) seem to assume that all Muslims are practicing. If that is the case, then 6% of Europeans in 2010 were practicing Muslims, while the percentage of practicing Christians in each country could be either less or more than that.

[edit: The organization [ORELA has numbers for Belgian francophones](http://www.o-re-la.org/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=1476:un-sondage-orela/ipsos/le-soir/rtbf-les-belges-francophones-et-la-religion&Itemid=85&lang=en): practicing Catholics outnumber Muslims in total, but practicing Muslims outnumber Catholics in the city of Brussels, and among children.]

This makes Mr. Geens' claim seem much more reasonable, although it's hard to measure exactly. It does depend on his definition of "Europe," since while he may be judging France accurately, Poland has very few Muslims and very high church attendance, and other countries are in between (see map, above).

---

### Update, October 2017

An [advance article](https://academic.oup.com/socrel/article-abstract/doi/10.1093/socrel/srx015/3867006/Attitudes-toward-Abortion-among-the-Muslim?redirectedFrom=fulltext) was released to the journal *Sociology of Religion* entitled, "Attitudes toward Abortion among the Muslim Minority and Non-Muslim Majority in Cross-National Perspective: Can Religiosity Explain the Differences?" This article uses the EURISLAM religiosity data that was never uploaded to the EURISLAM website. It contains the following statistic: **10% of non-Muslims** in Belgium, France, Germany, Britain, and Switzerland consider themselves to be "practitioners," as opposed to **50% of Muslims**. This data comes from before the refugee crisis.

As I discussed in my answer to [Is “No Religion” world's fastest growing religion?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34529/is-no-religion-worlds-fastest-growing-religion/35352#35352), in the 1960s there was a general belief that populations would lose their religion as they became "civilized" or "post-industrial", but after the 1980s this hypothesis was widely discarded. Instead, it is recognized that some groups secularize and others do not.

To give a common-sense example, some liberal Christian populations in America became more secular after the 1960s, but others became more fundamentalist.

Sociological research indicates that Muslims in Europe do **not** secularize in the manner attributed to liberal American Christians in the 1960s.

- A 2012 [literature survey](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-soc-071811-145455) proposes, "Some children of immigrants try to follow a 'real' Islam that has been purified of culturally specific practices. Hostility toward Muslims may lead some to react by increasing their own religious involvement."
- A 2014 [study in the Netherlands](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13644-013-0128-z) found that Muslims living in immigrant communities tend to inherit religiosity more often.
- A 2016 [study in France](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/imre.12289/full) showed that Muslims inherit religiosity much more than Christians, although there is a possible decline among third-generation immigrants.

Obviously it is impossible to judge how many "practicing Muslims" there will be in Europe "very shortly," but with current demographic trends there is no indication that the population will lower.

Comment: This is a useful contribution but more detail is required for a full answer. The implications of alternative definitions of religion (practising or not) would be useful, for example, and some more detailed numbers/projections might provide more context.

Comment: @matt_black Thanks, you were right to call me out on that. I have updated to answer the actual claim being made.

Comment: It seems rather a large logical flaw to count a non-practicing follower of whatever religion as a follower of that religion.

Comment: @James how so? Non practicing followers are a subset of followers. Just be careful about what conclusions you draw from that way of counting and there is no problem

Comment: @Dawn: Because following and practicing are the same thing. Or at least it seems so to me.  But as I keep trying to say, there seems to be a lot of imprecision, or maybe even a double standard, in counting who belongs to different religions.

Comment: @jamesqf if following and practicing are the same thing, there are no non-practicing followers, so there is no problem

Comment: @Dawn: The problem is that it seems that a double standard is being applied in the original.  People are counted as Christian only if they actively follow/practice the religion, while anyone from an Islamic cultural background is counted as Muslim.  Thus the relative numbers are distorted, perhaps severely so.

Comment: @James k that criticism makes sense

Comment: Ramadan would seem like a good place to start.

Comment: I don't understand the comment above: it's not the case that "People are counted as Christian only if they actively follow/practice the religion, while anyone from an Islamic cultural background is counted as Muslim."

Comment: @jamesqf: "Because following and practicing are the same thing" and "logical flaw to count a non-practicing follower of whatever religion as a follower of that religion": a) the studies mentioned focus on countable scores (and rightly so, in that everything else will lead to even more fuzzy if not questionable measures). b) But different flavors of religion from their inside view put very different emphasis to practice. And what the practice is also differs (as the answer discusses): AFAIK, christianity among the abrahamitic religions sticks out from judaism and islam in that is is a more ...

Comment: private religion (goes moe easily with a secular division into government/society/public affairs on one side and religion on the other side). Moreover, protestant flavors think that the believer's relation to god is a very private affair between believer and god - and how those "two" set up this relationship is entirely their affair. So any given religious practice (in the countable sense for the scores) is something the believer can do (and should, if it helps their relationship with god) but that cannot per se be generalized and "empty practice" would not count as having merit. With such ...

Comment: ... flavors of a religion, you can have people who'd (correctly, from an outside point of view) identify as strong believers/followers, but who'd not be identified as such by looking for religious practices. In that sense I'd go with practicioners being a subset of followers. And yes, of course this can distort numbers. As can other factors such as the fuzziness of people being signed up with a christian church just because they were baptized as children and never bothered to formally sign out or to take time considering whether they believe or not (which is what the scores try to sort out).

Comment: @jamesqf: a) this works both ways: I also know people who were raised atheistic (as in god cannot exist [which btw already sounds halfway theistic to me, as opposed to e.g. no god(s) exist(s)]) and expressed decidedly theistic/christian world views, but never bothered to formally join any church (sent their kids to church-run kindergarten though). b) I remember someone who had not been baptized as child because the parents wanted the kids to have full freedom on religious decision. They decided to take baptism + confirmation in one stride saying the parents' idea was nice but nonsense because

Comment: ... either they raise you with the religious values or not - and that's what you end up with anyways (barely teenaged discussion - this was not like discussions we had as students). Sure, social pressure pushes people to pretend - but for Germany we have the situation that overall there is not much pressure to pretend being christian nowadays, though depending on your age when you grew up  there may have been. In the west towards christianity, in the east towards atheism (with current membership christian churches 40-80 ./. 20-30 %).

Comment: @anonymized: Sure, it works both ways, but I think statistically you'd find that there are more people leaving the religion they were brought up in (where there's no serious social pressure to conceal one's lack of belief) than there are people brought up non-religiously who later convert to a religion.  As for pressure, there may not be much among native German Christians, but I would guess you might find a lot among Muslim immigrant communities.  In the US, you'll find places, like the so-called Bible Belt, where there's significant community pressure, others where there's little or none.